# javascript/jquery event not firing with refresh

Tags: jquery, regex, refresh

I'm using some code to find any @ and # tags for social media stuff. the loop re fires every x seconds. outside the refreshing loop it work fine, but inside it wont fire. Below is the code:

```
    (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
            $('#main').fadeOut("fast").load(location.href + " #main>*", "").fadeIn("fast");
            //apply any new hashtags

            /*
             *   Hashtags
             */
            hashtag_regexp = /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

            function linkHashtags(text) {
                return text.replace(
                hashtag_regexp,
                    '<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
            }
            atMention_regexp = /@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

            function linkatMention(text) {
                return text.replace(
                atMention_regexp,
                    '<span class="mention">@$1</span>');
            }

            $('p').each(function () {
                $(this).html(linkatMention($(this).html()));
                $(this).html(linkHashtags($(this).html()));
            });

        }, 10000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You are re-declaring your functions inside the setInterval handler... Best put them just inside your `ready` function. Also you can make the whole ready handler `jQuery(function($){YOUR CODE HERE});` as a shortcut, and still have a scoped `$`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample piece of HTML for testing? (Just save-as from a browser)

Comment: You also need to stop it processing any existing span tags as it goes recursive! On it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rehashed your code a bit, but works fine now:

- I moved your functions to outside the `setInterval` as they should not be declared over and over.
- I made the bit that does the work another function and call it initially as well as in the timer
- I nested the `html` modification calls to speed things up.
- Used a local $this variable to avoid multiple jQuery selector calls.
- I added checks to ensure the processing was not applied to a paragraph twice (it was nesting spans infinitely every 10 seconds).

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cs369/6/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    /*
     *   Hashtags
     */
    var hashtag_regexp = /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

    function linkHashtags(text) {
        if (text.indexOf('"hashtag"') == -1) {
            return text.replace(
            hashtag_regexp,
                '<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
        }
        return text;
    }

    var atMention_regexp = /@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

    function linkatMention(text) {
        if (text.indexOf('"mention"') == -1) {
        return text.replace(
        atMention_regexp,
            '<span class="mention">@$1</span>');
        }
        return text;
    }

    function updateMentions() {
        $('p').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.html(linkatMention(linkHashtags($this.html())));
        });

    }

    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $('#main').fadeOut("fast").load(location.href + " #main>*", "").fadeIn("fast");
        //apply any new hashtags
        updateMentions();

    }, 10000);
    updateMentions();
});
```

Tip: You can use the shortcut syntax for document ready `$(function(){});` with `jQuery(function ($) {});` so that you define `$` locally-scoped.

Comment: Thanks, this looks a lot more readable too! This is going to be a noob question, but when I run it, I'm getting an error of html being undefined in the return html. I'm running jquery 1.11 as well :/

Comment: Whoops. Typo... All fixed. That was meant to simply return the parameter passed, but I lost track of the names (sometimes I hate weakly typed languages - which is why I use TypeScript instead of raw JavaScript) :)

Comment: Thanks! Looking at TypeScript now :)

Comment: I cannot recommend TypeScript enough. All my JavaScript is now clean and highly object-orientated. If you use Visual Studio 2013 you now get fully integrated support and debugging (which is unbeatable for productivity).